# How to Set SystemTray Color

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, system-tray

I was attempting to change the color of the `SystemTray`, but for some reason I cannot get it to work correctly. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="Cyan"
```

Is this not correct?

Comment: Have you tried from code behind `SystemTray.BackgroundColor = System.Windows.Media.Colors.Cyan;`?

Comment: Yes, that did not work either unfortunately. The background shows up white.

Comment: Then try `SystemTray.BackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Cyan;`

Comment: I figured out what's causing the problem. Setting the background does work, but I am using a package from NuGet called PhoneThemeManager, in which I am setting the device's theme to Light, and this is not letting me set the SystemTray background color.

Comment: That's great. Post your comment as answer so other user can get help from it.

Comment: you need to confirm the Opacity property too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="Cyan"
```

Is the proper solution. I am using PhoneThemeManager from NuGet which automatically overrides device defaults to force either light or dark theme. Setting the `SystemTray.Background` using the above code is causing the Background to be white. Not sure how to fix this specific issue, but in all other cases the above code should work.

Comment: You need to set "ThemeManager.OverrideOptions = ThemeManagerOverrideOptions.ApplicationBarColors;"