# Windows Phone 8 App - How to change color of clock and top bar icons

Tags: windows-phone-8, colors, themes

I am creating some WP8 app and I want to change foreground color of the most top bar where the clock and other icons like WiFi or telephone network range. I want to do something like in linkedin app where clock and others become blue. Like this:
[image]
Anybody knows how o do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Set SystemTray Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780470/how-to-set-systemtray-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it in xaml, BTW it is called System Tray not top bar.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
...
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="Blue">
...
```

Hope this helped you